# HADOOP Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell

Tags: hadoop

I'm building a wordcounter program and I want to create a working directory in the HDFS, but when I execute `hdfs dfs -mkdir wordcount` or other commands from hdfs dfs command list it returns me `Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell`. Google have told me that maybe it is a problem with path variable, but i checked it and it's ok. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error means `hadoop classpath` command has issues, not `PATH`.

And you don't need HDFS to run or learn MapReduce / Spark WordCount code. It works fine on your local filesystem as well